NPM dependency over git+ssh behind proxy
In one of our Node.js projects, there is the following dependency in the package.json file:
"cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr": "git+https://bitbucket.org/bhivedevs/cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr.git"

For some reason, once I run npm i, this turns out in the package-lock.json as follows:
"resolved": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/bhivedevs/cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr.git#9f627f0d36dbb8ee544fb9b2174f6f127c878e3c"

However the CI/CD build machine is behind a corporate firewall that blocks all non-HTTP connections, so the run of npm i eventually fails with this error:
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! A git connection error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@bitbucket.org/bhivedevs/cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr.git
npm ERR! ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

I'm not too familiar with NPM, or with that project; I'm just a DevOps guy who is responsible for getting the CI/CD process to work.
Opening the firewall for outgoing SSH connections is not an option. So what options do I have?
Why does the URL of the dependency get changed from "git+https://" to "git+ssh://" at all? Is there a way to prevent this?

The quick solution would be for the devs to download the package as a .tgz (they can checkout the package, and run npm pack to get this file), then they can install the package from a local file in the package.json, that should resolve the ssh issue.
